# Spring MVC: Show data in a table row?

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, html-table

I am trying to display `data` in a `table row`. However it is just showing the `var name` as output, e.g:

```
Name | age
User1| {age}
```

I am using `Spring-MVC` along with `Spring Boot`. I have created other mapping classes and their data is showing correctly in `HTML <p> tags`.

**My Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/age")
    public String age(@RequestParam(value="age", required=false, defaultValue="5") String age, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("age", age);
        return "age";
    }
}
```

**age.html: (uses ThymeLeaf)**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Age Table</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Age</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>User1</td>
        <td>${age}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the http request like? can you provide the url ? If post method show the form

Comment: I' ve never used tymeleaf, but if it works like a jsp I recommend you to check the inclusions. Your code is OK, the fact your view is an HTML rather than a jsp or a server side processed page may cause issues in using ${}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User 1</td>
            <td th:text="${age}"> Age </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

If you have a list of age like this:

```
    List<Integer> listOfAge = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(23,45,45,23,54,23,43));
    model.addAttribute("listOfAge", listOfAge);
```

then try this:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Sr. No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="age,iterationstatus :${listOfAge}">
            <td th:text="${iterationstatus.count}">1</td>
            <td>User 1</td>
            <td th:text="${age}"> Age </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```