# Thymeleaf Spring 4 can't render Expression Language

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I integrate Spring 4 MVC and Thymeleaf. And i successfully get my active template based on my Controller.
But when i add request attribute to my View,  my request attribute can't render the value.
I think it's automatically.

Here is my XML configuration file :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.fanjavaid" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />

    <!-- THYMELEAF CONFIGURATION -->
    <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"></property>
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5"></property> 
    </bean>
    <bean id="templateEngine"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" /> 
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"></property>
    </bean>
```

Here is My Controller :

```
@Controller
public class JobseekerController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Welcome to Spring 4 MVC");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

And here is my View :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Welcome Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${message}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

My View is HTML file.

Comment: Try this: `<h1 th:text="${message}"> Message </h1>` and see this for more [Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35678403/spring-mvc-show-data-in-a-table-row/35682372#35682372).

Answer (score 2):

fanjavaid,

I just think you need to add some code.

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:text="${message}">hi</h1>



</body>
</html>
```

You search thymeleaf tutorial